# Export MySQL database structure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database. I would like to export the tables/structure to a script.

I don't need the data, just a script to create all tables I have.

I have access to PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select your database go to Export tab then check structure checkbox and uncheck data check box then at bottom check save as check box and write your script name and push go button.